# How can I create a function in Apps Script that takes a String as a parameter and then return information specific to that String?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is the issue I am facing. I am currently making an expense tracker on Google Sheets:

[image: Here is a preview]

I would like to implement a feature where the user could put in a String as a parameter in the function, and then have the percentage of their clothing expenses in regards to that particular String... if that makes sense. For example `myFunction("Zara")` would return 33.7%, because the sum of all clothing expenses is 2433, and the client spent 821 on Zara clothing. Therefore, (821/2433)*100 = 33.7.

So far, I believe the function should be declared like this `function myFunction(string, values)`. Then, I would initialize a variable `sum` to 0, and loop through every value in the sheet. I'm really confused as to how I would approach this, and I apologize if I made little sense, as I am new to JavaScript and programming in general.

[image: Alternate Version]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### solution#1

You don't need a custom function, try

```
=sumif($A$2:$A,D2,$B$2:$B)/sum($B$2:$B)
```

[image]

### solution#2

If you want a custom function, try

```
=perCent("B")
```

with the following script

```
function perCent(categ){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var values = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues()
  var total = 0
  var sum = 0
  values.forEach(function(row){
    total+=row[1]
    if (row[0]==categ){sum+=row[1]}
  })
  return sum/total
}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this in a less complicated way? I believe that for this method, i would have to write the names of the clothing companies in another column. For my other custom functions, the user would just write it in a cell, like such. `function myFunction(`, select the values in the parameter of the function, and the answer would be returned to them once they click enter. I hope that made sense and sorry for the bother.

Comment: ok, see solution #2

Comment: this worked great on the first image i provided. however, how would i change the code if my sheet looked different? i updated my post with another image. The expenses are in Row B, and the clothing brands are in Row H. Thanks!

Comment: replace row[0] by row[7]

Comment: that doesnt seem to work. ```function perCent(categ){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var values = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues()
  var total = 0
  var sum = 0
  values.forEach(function(row){
    total+=row[1]
    if (row[7]==categ){sum+=row[1]}
  })
  return sum/total
}```

Here's what i have, and when I put the function in Google Sheets, it returns 0 to me.

Comment: `var values = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues()` perhaps this line also needs to be changed?

Comment: yes, you should have post a spreadsheet instead of images ... `var values = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()`

Comment: I apologize as I don't know how to post a spreadsheet. I have another question though; why did you remove the `2` from the original function? Thanks for the help !!

Comment: 2 means previously 2 columns, ie A and B; now you have more than 2, it's why I change for sh.getLastColumn()

Comment: thank you for your kindness and your assistance, much appreciated!